# Rails - JQuery - Form - Autofill field based on another

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, onchange

I have a form that has many itens that depend of the first item, the Student_ID (id_aluno in portuguese), to be filled.

I have a collection select to select the "aluno". It shows the name but writes the id in database.

```
<%= f.collection_select :id_aluno, Aluno.order('nome'), :id, :nome %>
```

The second item is the id of the plan that the student pays for. It is a column in student table called "plano".

```
<%= f.text_field :plano %>
```

I need fill the second item based on the first (student). I think it's called "onchange".

```
class Pagamento < ActiveRecord::Base   <---- class of the FORM
belongs_to :pag1, :class_name => "Aluno", :foreign_key => "id_aluno"
has_one :pag2, :class_name => "Aluno", :foreign_key => "id_plano"
end

class Aluno < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :pag3, :class_name => "Pagamento", :foreign_key => "id_aluno"
end
```

I need a help to write the JQuery for that.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to send an Ajax request onchange of the first field. And change the second div based on the param passed. If you can update your question with first item and the 2nd item(which is dynamically generated) it would be useful.

Comment: Hi! The second item is there!